# Angular custom click to edit - input value to function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a basic click to edit span field in my code, which prompts an input box and a couple of buttons:

```
    <span ng-click="editField()" ng-if="edit === false">Your text to edit</span>

    <div ng-if="edit === true">
        <input type="text" ng-bind="data.field" value="Your text to edit" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="update(data.field, 'somename')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancelEdit()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
    </div>
```

When the user saves, the `update` function is called. However, the issue I'm having is that how do I send whatever text the user inputs, towards my angular logic, without settings the text values in an object at the start of the controller?

Heres an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/43GUa/1/

Basically it prints in the console: `undefined + somename`

How do I get that `undefined` to the text in the input field? I can't use `ng-model` since I'm unable to declare my object data(?) in my controller.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-bind` replaces the text of the element with the value, you want to use `ng-model` for two-way binding to the value of the control ([***fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/xkjdj/2)):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.field"/>
```

Why don't you want to set the value at the start?  If you want the value to come from the HTML you should write a directive.  If you are doing this in more than one place you could write something to update a field or to call a function:

```
<my-editable update="data.field">Your text to edit</my-editable>
<!-- or -->
<my-editable update="updateValue($value, 'somename')">Your text to edit</my-editable>
```

If you *really* don't want to do that, you could pass `$event` to `editField()` and load `data.field` with the value then:

```
$scope.editField = function(event) {
    $scope.edit = true;
    $scope.data.field = event.target.innerText;
 };

 <span ng-click="editField($event)" ng-if="edit === false">Your text to edit</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, the event bit worked :) And it's not a matter of not wanting to, it's just the environment it's working on won't allow it that easily :)